# Video tag is not working

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I'm trying to create a movie player on my localhost but I have an issue, when I try to play a movie (.mp4) file it seems like my video is not loaded (movie size is 2.4gb) but when I try with another .mp4 file with less size (60mb) works perfectly! I'm using video html tag and I tried with videojs but I have the same issue.

This is a short example of what I'm using:

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
       poster="Images/Image1.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="RootFolder/Pelicula2.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
        <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
</video>
```

What could be the problem and what can I do to solve it? Maybe its a problem with my source src? Should I try it with another format?

UPDATE:

I change my Files folder to my desktop and now this is my code:

```
<video controls>
    <source src="C:\Users\franc\Desktop\Movies\Pelicula2.mp4" />
</video>
```

With this I get the following error message `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/franc/Desktop/Movies/Pelicula2.mp4` but when I click on that hyperlink it opens another window and the video is displayed properly.

Comment: if you are loading the page via http:// then you can only load assets that way, and not via file://

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Yes! I was reading about it and now seems to work properly, I just move my project folder to another one in my wwwroot folder and now works, the other thing is to change file to http://myurl like you said, if you want you can post that as answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using

> C:\Users\franc\Desktop\Movies\Pelicula2.mp4

is allowing the browser to access content from the user local system which is not allowed to do directly in the browser you can host your video on any blob like amazon s3 or Microsoft azure or if you have to put that folder in your c:\ directory you will need to create a simple server that serves this file to the client maybe you can look into Node.js it will be your easiest solution specially if you have experience working with JavaScript

Edit :
After doing some research i found that you can disable this security feature in your browser manually just type the following in the Terminal

```
> "C:\PathTo\Chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Make sure you replace PathTo with the current path of chrome on your system

source : http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/